# Why doesn't helm use the name defined in the deployment template?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

i.e. from `name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Values.module5678.name }}-pod` below

```
# deployment.yaml

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: {{ template "project1234.name" . }}
    chart: {{ template "project1234.chart" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
  name: {{ template "project1234.module5678.fullname" . }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ template "project1234.name" . }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ template "project1234.name" . }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: "{{ .Values.image.name }}:{{ .Values.image.tag }}"
        name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Values.module5678.name }}-pod
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1234
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: {{ .Values.image.pullSecret }}
```

I am expecting the pod name to be:

> pod/project1234-module5678-pod

Instead, the resulting Pod name is:

> pod/chartname-project1234-module5678-dc7db787-skqvv

...where (in my understanding):
**chartname** is from: `helm install --name chartname -f values.yaml .`
**project1234** is from:

```
# Chart.yaml

apiVersion: v1
appVersion: "1.0"
description: project1234 Helm chart for Kubernetes
name: project1234
version: 0.1.0
```

**module5678** is from:

```
# values.yaml

rbac:
  create: true

serviceAccounts:
  module5678:
    create: true
    name:

image:
  name: <image location>
  tag: 1.5
  pullSecret: <pull secret>

gitlab:
  secretName: <secret name>
  username: foo
  password: bar

module5678:
  enabled: true
  name: module5678
  ingress:
    enabled: true
  replicaCount: 1
  resources: {}
```

I've tried changing `name: {{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Values.module5678.name }}-pod` into a plain string value like "podname1234" and it isn't followed. I even tried removing the name setting entirely and the resulting pod name remains the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pods created from a Deployment always have a generated name based on the Deployment's name (and also the name of the intermediate ReplicaSet, if you go off and look for it).  You can't override it.

Given the YAML you've shown, I'd expect that this fragment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ template "project1234.module5678.fullname" . }}
```

expands out to a Deployment name of `chartname-project1234-module5678`; the remaining bits are added in by the ReplicaSet and then the Pod itself.

If you do look up the Pod and `kubectl describe pod chartname-project1234-module5678-dc7db787-skqvv` you will probably see that it has a single container that has the expected name `project1234-module5678-pod`.  Pretty much the only time you need to use this is if you need to `kubectl logs` (or, more rarely, `kubectl exec`) in a multi-container pod; if you are in this case, you'll appreciate having a shorter name, and since the container names are always scoped to the specific pod in which they appear, there's nothing wrong with using a short fixed name here

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: container
```

Comment: This has been very enlightening. Thank you very much for your time!