# Where does the pod name come from in Helm?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I just installed a kubernetes cluster by borrowing from `helm/charts/stable/hadoop`.
Now all my pods have a prefix of "`listening-snail`"

Where did this come from? I am searching hi and low in all configuration files and I cannot find anything. Of course I didn't supply it on the commandline either!!!

```
$  helm install --namespace hadoopns hadoop 
NAME:   listening-snail
LAST DEPLOYED: Tue Jul 30 22:04:03 2019
NAMESPACE: hadoopns
STATUS: DEPLOYED

RESOURCES:
==> v1/ConfigMap
NAME                    DATA  AGE
listening-snail-hadoop  8     0s

==> v1/Pod(related)
NAME                              READY  STATUS             RESTARTS  AGE
listening-snail-hadoop-hdfs-dn-0  0/1    ContainerCreating  0         0s
listening-snail-hadoop-hdfs-nn-0  0/1    ContainerCreating  0         0s
listening-snail-hadoop-yarn-nm-0  0/1    ContainerCreating  0         0s
listening-snail-hadoop-yarn-rm-0  0/1    ContainerCreating  0         0s

...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53489331/7568391), `listening-snail` comes from your StatefulSet name.

StatefulSet name in `charts/stable/hadoop`'s  [hdfs-dn-statefulset.yaml](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/hadoop/templates/hdfs-dn-statefulset.yaml) is

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: {{ include "hadoop.fullname" . }}-hdfs-dn
```

`hadoop.fullname` is defined in [_helpers.tpl](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/hadoop/templates/_helpers.tpl)

```
 {{/*
Create a default fully qualified app name.
We truncate at 63 chars because some Kubernetes name fields are limited to this (by the DNS naming spec).
*/}}
{{- define "hadoop.fullname" -}}
{{- $name := default .Chart.Name .Values.nameOverride -}}
{{- printf "%s-%s" .Release.Name $name | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" -}}
{{- end -}}
```

So, if you don't supply `--name` parameter with your `helm install` command, it's random `.Release.Name`-`hadoop` generated by helm (where `hadoop` is `.Chart.Name` and can be overwritten by `nameOverride` in your *values.yaml* file).

[Documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/#helm-install-installing-a-package)